# Python regex search or compare with escape characters does not return true

Tags: python, regex, string-comparison

Trying to figure out why these do not compare:

```
import re
re.search( "Hello \\ World", "Hello \\ World" ) <> None
or
re.search( r"Hello \\ World", r"Hello \\ World" ) <> None
```

I am testing data coming back from a data base in JSON format with data that is used to perform actions in the code.  I'm using re because I sometimes want to ask if the returned content contains a partial phrase.  So re gives me quite a bit of flexibility.  I had expected that the raw comparison to work but it isn't and, of course, I can't expect the database to return raw strings. I can't control what is in the database so I want to find a way to allow these comparisons to work.  Your suggestions / ideas much appreciated.  TY in advance.

Comment: you mean you're getting `None` and you don't know why?

Comment: Note that backslashes are special characters in regex, too...

Comment: "I can't expect the database to return raw strings": that's nonsense. raw strings are for literal strings. A string is a string.

Comment: The strings were meant to be exact matches. I upper cased the W in world on the first parameter.  Understood about the raw strings but that WAS the point.

Answer (score 0):

several problems in your regexes

1. regex search is case-sensitive by default, you're submitting words with different casing
2. first example: double backslash, not raw, translates in backslash, escapes the following space in the regex (escaping space amounts to space: does nothing). To get a match you have to do

   `print(re.search( "Hello \\ world", "Hello  World" ,re.IGNORECASE))`  (note the 2 spaces in the string to match)
3. second example: double backslash, raw, translates in backslash char, and backslash which escapes the  following space in the regex. To get a match you have to do:

   `print(re.search( r"Hello \\ world", r"Hello \ World" ,re.IGNORECASE))`

now testing both statements: it works

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 12), match='Hello  World'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 13), match='Hello \\ World'>
```

(use `r` prefix at all times when writing regexes, that's one less problem)

Comment: I just found the answer before coming here and see that Jean-François came up with the same fix that I found.  Double escaping solves the issue for me.  IOW:  Searching for \\\\ when there are two back slashes in the original text allows the search to complete successfully.  Thanks for the help guys.